# why I am getting error to find out correlation of one variable with all the other variables in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

Consider the below dataset (imported as pandas df):

```
Chinese Yuan    Euro    Japanese Yen    U.K. Pound Sterling U.S. Dollar Indian Rupee
9.29446 1.25367 143.645 1.05054 1.39596 94.1451
9.31515 1.25322 142.715 1.06143 1.39684 94.1513
9.31697 1.25834 140.54  1.073   1.39286 NA
9.31315 1.25737 140.64  1.06911 1.39316 94.0345
9.3135  1.25797 140.51  1.07261 1.39257 93.9408
9.29403 1.25769 139.962 1.0705  1.38962 93.3027
9.31021 1.2549  143.369 1.05762 1.39194 93.4641
9.3135  1.25716 145.178 1.0468  1.39193 93.5445
9.30432 1.24695 144.895 1.05236 1.39122 93.0917
9.31532 1.25263 147.268 1.04242 1.39392 NA
9.30354 1.25652 NA  1.04952 1.38883 93.1923
```

What I wanted to do is to find out correlation of `Indian Rupee` and all other currencies and for that purpose, I am trying to use the below python code:

```
df['Indian Rupee'].corr(~df['Indian Rupee'])
```

Above has thrown an error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'invert' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

**I want to understand why the above error? Why I can't find correlation this way?**

What alternative do I have here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to do the correlation on the whole dataframe, then just select the column you care about

```
df.corr()['Indian Rupee']

ChineseYuan          0.304050
Euro                 0.243851
JapaneseYen         -0.270123
U.K.PoundSterling    0.314681
U.S.Dollar           0.872862
IndianRupee          1.000000
Name: IndianRupee, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 3):

`~` is bitwise negate operator. You can negate a boolean (series) or an integer (series). You can't negate a float series, which is *not safe*.

In other words `~df['Indian Rupee']` doesn't exclude other columns for you. If you want to drop, use:

```
df.drop('Indian Rupee', axis=1)
```

So you can do

```
df.drop('Indian Rupee', axis=1).corrwith(df['Indian Rupee'])
```

Output:

```
Chinese Yuan           0.267802
Japanese Yen          -0.270123
U.K. Pound Sterling    0.197496
U.S. Dollar            0.846584
dtype: float64
```